# Ubuntu repo sync error

Tags: ubuntu

When I run command repo sync I get error:
error: command 'sync' requires repo to be installed first.Use "repo init" to install it here.
How to fix this?
I have installed repo init.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, 'repo init' is a command, that inits your repo.
Be sure that 'repo' is installed by typing 'repo --version' (should return your 'repo' version)

If not follow this : https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/
Create a $HOME/bin folder to put 'repo' binary into it, and then be sure that it's in your $PATH (path=$HOME/bin:$PATH for example)

Then, use 'repo init' to initialize your repository, like in https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html (better to have in mind a manifest instead of default) : 
$ repo init -u  []

Once initialized, then you will be able to sync (based on the anifest you gave).